# Locate an an element by the value of the precedent element - Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I want to locate the input based on the value of the previous td --> 143753
taking in consideration that i will put the value 143753 in a variable, so i can choose any row i want to select.

```
<td style="width:11%;">143753</td>
<td align="right" style="width:10%;">
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$cphContent$wucOrderPos$gvPOSSelection$ctl03$btnSelectPos" value="Select" id="cphContent_wucOrderPos_gvPOSSelection_btnSelectPos_1" class="button">
</td>
```

This screenshot will make what I want to do more clear:

[image: This screenshot will make what I want to do more clear]

My Attempt:

```
//*[@value="Select"]//preceding-sibling::td[@text()='143753']
```

Comment: Please post your attempt at doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only contains(text(),'') worked for me for this case**

```
//td[contains(text(),'174013')]/following-sibling::td/input[@value="Select"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Java* solution:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[text()='143753']//following-sibling::td[1]/input[@class='button' and @value='Select']")));
  ```
- *Python* solution:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[text()='143753']//following-sibling::td[1]/input[@class='button' and @value='Select']")))
  ```
- **Note** (*Python* solution) : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to get the input field value if the td value is '143753':

```
//td[text()='143753']/following-sibling::td/input[@value="Select"]
```

so here we will first check for td with the value you mentioned , then will check if it has any following sibbling with tag td, then we will see if it has and immediate child element input with value as 'select'